# Trying to replicate this excel Xlookup formula in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, excel-formula

```
=XLOOKUP(A2, $F$2:$F$350640, $E$2:$E$350640,,-1) * XLOOKUP(C2, $C:$C, $B:$B)
```

Columns A and F have different time interval data.

I am using the following but the final output does not calculate some values or there are missing values (don't know the reason):

```py
a_column = 'A'
c_column = 'C'
f_column = 'F'
e_column = 'E'
c_lookup_range = df['C']
b_lookup_range = df['B']

a_index = np.searchsorted(df[f_column], df[a_column], side='right')
c_index = np.searchsorted(c_lookup_range, df[c_column], side='right')

xlookup_result_1 = df[e_column].values[a_index - 1]
xlookup_result_2 = b_lookup_range.values[c_index - 1]

final_result = xlookup_result_1 * xlookup_result_2
```

Comment: Please share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Provide a small portion of sample data along with the expected output and what errors your code produces (or why your code's results are not  correct).